# ClojureClr source macro: Source not found for standard library functions

Tags: clojure, clojureclr

I'm trying to print the source code for a function but I get `Source not found`

```
user=> (source map)
; Source not found
; nil
```

I am using ClojureClr 1.6.0 by running Clojure.Main.exe. I don't have any clojure `.clj` source files. What am I missing?

#### Edit:

It says here that the file is `clojure/core.clj`,

```
user=> (meta (resolve `map)) 
; .....   :file "clojure/core.clj", .....
```

should that folder be in some specific path? relative to the repl or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the source and copied it to the `Clojure.Main.exe` folder and it works now.

[This](http://www.braveclojure.com/organization/) is a great tutorial about how clojure's namespaces and libraries work and their relationship with the filesystem.